# ion-input losing focus for ion-item after some clicks

Tags: html, ionic-framework, input, focus

I have an ion-input inside a ion-item and I realized that after some clicks on the ion-input it stops to receive focus. After some debug I noted that it starts to fire the click event on the ion-item instead of giving focus to the ion-input. This bug only happens on the ion-inputs which type is not 'text'. I also tried to remove all of CSS classes, but the bug still persists. Usually, the bug occurs after 2 clicks.

The bug was also happening on ion-inputs of type 'text', but after update some packages and remove the `"this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);"` from the app.component.ts file, the problem was solved, but only for the ion-input 'text' types. Also, the bug only happens on ion-inputs when inside an ion-item.

This is a html of an ion-input inside an ion-item

```
<ion-item >
   <ion-label floating>E-mail</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/push": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
        "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.13.0",
        "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
        "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
        "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.0.19",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.6.3",
        "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.24",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.11",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^2.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.6.0",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
        "firebase": "^4.5.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "intl": "^1.2.5",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "rxjs": "5.5.2",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
        "ionic": "3.18.0",
        "typescript": "2.4.2",
        "@angular/cli": "^1.0.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
            "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "<Cliente ID>"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {},
            "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
            "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
        },
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "browser",
            "ios"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./scripts/copy-custom-lib.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue!! Did you got any work around for it?

Comment: Unfortunately not =/

Comment: adding `disabled="false"` to the password field worked for me!! Try it.

Comment: The problem still persists after adding `disabled="false"`...

Comment: I think there is a issue with some package, since the problem doesn't occur on a blank project.